# What is a modern approach to similarity search?

Tags: python, nlp, similarity

Given is a list of text files. Each text file describes a topic. Input is a mental concept that I describe with a few sentences.

The text files contain umlauts.

The algorithm should output the files and probability for each that the concept described is being dealt with.

My Pseudocode:

```
split the concept by the space literal and put words into an array, while omitting stopwords
iterate over each text file
    split by the space literal and put words into an array, while omitting stopwords
    i = 0
    iterate over vector
        if vectorword in concept
            i++
    determine percentage by using i/vectorcount * 100
    save the percentage in a dictionary filename - percentage
sort dictionary by percentage descendingly
output
```

Drawbacks I see in this approach:

1. The output would not include similar words but only the words used.
2. The code is redundant, iterating over each text file should only be done once and then one should work with a faster approach, like a database

Comment: There are lot of algorithms like this in NLP..what are you exactly looking for ?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @depperm I updated the question

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Please see the updated version. What terms do I look for in nlp?

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

From https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1wXmqj3LAL6juxvQY_IHTtZAMuN46YZdV

```
import itertools

import torch

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

import numpy as np

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

def cos(a, b):
    return cosine_similarity(torch.tensor(a).view(1, -1), torch.tensor(b).view(1, -1))[0][0]


# Printing candies, make sure that arrays 
# are ellipsis and humanly readable.
np.set_printoptions(precision=4, threshold=10)

# The URL that hosts the DAN model for Universal Sentence Encoder 
module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2"

embed = hub.Module(module_url)

bulbasaur = """A strange seed was planted on its back at birth. The plant sprouts and grows with this POKéMON."""
ivysaur = """When the bulb on its back grows large, it appears to lose the ability to stand on its hind legs."""
venusaur = """The plant blooms when it is absorbing solar energy. It stays on the move to seek sunlight."""

charmander = """Obviously prefers hot places. When it rains, steam is said to spout from the tip of its tail."""
charmeleon = """When it swings its burning tail, it elevates the temperature to unbearably high levels."""
charizard = """Spits fire that is hot enough to melt boulders. Known to cause forest fires unintentionally."""

input_texts = [bulbasaur, ivysaur, venusaur, 
              charmander, charmeleon, charizard]

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
    sentence_embeddings = session.run(embed(input_texts))

names = ['bulbasaur', 'ivysaur  ', 'venusaur', 
         'charmander', 'charmeleon', 'charizard']

for (mon1, vec1), (mon2, vec2) in itertools.product(zip(names, sentence_embeddings), repeat=2):
    print('\t'.join(map(str, [mon1, mon2, cos(vec1, vec2)])))
```

[out]:

```
bulbasaur   bulbasaur   1.0000002
bulbasaur   ivysaur     0.5978951
bulbasaur   venusaur    0.57630616
bulbasaur   charmander  0.27358365
bulbasaur   charmeleon  0.36671823
bulbasaur   charizard   0.3608557
ivysaur     bulbasaur   0.5978951
ivysaur     ivysaur     1.0
ivysaur     venusaur    0.5274135
ivysaur     charmander  0.34133852
ivysaur     charmeleon  0.54503417
ivysaur     charizard   0.26368174
venusaur    bulbasaur   0.57630616
venusaur    ivysaur     0.5274135
venusaur    venusaur    0.99999994
venusaur    charmander  0.37098676
venusaur    charmeleon  0.50332355
venusaur    charizard   0.50058115
charmander  bulbasaur   0.27358365
charmander  ivysaur     0.34133852
charmander  venusaur    0.37098676
charmander  charmander  1.0000001
charmander  charmeleon  0.58522964
charmander  charizard   0.4640133
charmeleon  bulbasaur   0.36671823
charmeleon  ivysaur     0.54503417
charmeleon  venusaur    0.50332355
charmeleon  charmander  0.58522964
charmeleon  charmeleon  1.0000001
charmeleon  charizard   0.59804976
charizard   bulbasaur   0.3608557
charizard   ivysaur     0.26368174
charizard   venusaur    0.50058115
charizard   charmander  0.4640133
charizard   charmeleon  0.59804976
charizard   charizard   1.0000001
```

See https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2 for details

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking I would use word embedding --> some variations of doc2vec and apply it on your text files, store these vectors. For the mental concept input I would do the same and then search for the most similar vectors. I kinda like spacy tools
https://spacy.io/api/doc and https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity should point you to the right way.